# What is the point of the Jacobi accessory equation?

Tags: variational-analysis

In [Where does Jacobi's accessory equation come from?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1717565/where-does-jacobis-accessory-equation-come-from) Chappers gives two derivations of the Jacobi accessory equation. From the first, it is clear that the Jacobi accessory equation is a means to ensure that a stationary point of the functional is a minimum, given $p>0$.

However, what does the second derivation tell us? Why would we divide by $h$ and take the limit?